# Apple App rejection due to non native buttons and features

Tags: ios, cordova, appstore-approval

While developing a phonegap smartphone application which runs on ios/android and bb v6+, im using a web service call to google maps and using  tags for navigating through the application. I received an answer from apple with the following rejection message:

> We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:
>   - Did not include iOS features. For example, it would be appropriate to use native iOS buttons and iOS features. 
>   Additional user interactive features are needed.

My app has 2 buttons, one for searching and one to view the search results, both of which are non-native, html < button > tags.

Is it possible to use the native iOS buttons with a phonegap project,  i.e using the search button (magnifying glass with word 'search' underneath),  with a plugin?

Is it possible that my app was rejected for using a Google Maps web service call? if that were the case, i imagine the rejection message would be similar to the rejection message seen [in this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425065/app-rejection-due-to-google-map-branding)

Any ideas/suggestions/guidelines would be great, 
thanks

Comment: It is quite rare that Apple uses this reason to reject apps. Can you post a screenshot ? If you make use of PhoneGap , did you use jQuery Mobile as well ?

Comment: I have not seen your buttons but it sounds like they offend your Apple reviewer. You should use a toolkit that provides native looking buttons in HTML.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: no, did not use jquery, simply javascript. Also, screenshots of the Android equivalent can be found here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iata.mobile&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5pYXRhLm1vYmlsZSJd

Comment: @Simon MacDonald, would you recommend any toolkit for this purpose?

Comment: jQuery Mobile, Sencha, Dojo Mobile, etc.

Comment: AzurGroup.. Did you managed to get your application accepted? .. Would be interested to hear what you had to change

Comment: yes! actually, our application was finally accepted by Apple. We decided to rewrite with jQuery/jQuery Mobile. After our conversion was completed, we resubmitted but were rejected again. Apple made some more suggestions and after reading the 200 page HIG (Human Interface Guidelines), we made changes based on their suggestions (which were EXTREMELY VAGUE, by the way), resubmitted the application and were approved. Our guess to the rejection was not only a lack of "Apple-look-and-feel" to the application, but also a 'lack of features'. We added some more features an we had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the [NativeControls](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NativeControls) plugin. Judging by your screenshots a the iOS tab bar should work well with your app.

Comment: Thank you Louis! I will definitely take a look at your suggestion
cheers

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it works out for you. ;) By the way another "trick" that you could try is to simply re-submit the app for review... Often another reviewer will decide differently.

Comment: not a problem, will work on implementing the plugin tomorrow and will update accordingly.
interesting 'trick'... definitely something to try :)

Comment: your suggest was useful and i liked the way the Native Controls Plugin worked but, i had to abandon the idea of using this plugin because i ran into development problems that i wasnt sure how to overcome. I guess the lack of documentation and examples was to blame. In the end, i switched to jquery mobile. It's  probably not as stable as the native controls plugin, but i rewrote my entire app in 2.5 days with jquery whereas i had spent over 3 trying to model a few pages.

In the future, if i need to create another app i will definitely consider this plugin. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not using native controls isn't a problem in itself.  However, your app is too close to the appearance of a standard iOS settings page, which means that anything which doesn't exactly match that will feel broken.